# logging in iPhone different profile settings

Tags: applications, iphone, settings

Is there a setting or an app that does this:

When iPhone asked me for my passcode lock it will identify my passcode what passcode I entered and when passcode matches, it will match to the profile it was associated.

Example, A passcode that is "1234" will go to my public profile setting which is when i'm outside. So settings like app arrangement, wallpaper and other settings will adjust.

And when I enter "4782" it will associate it to my home/private setting and will adjust the settings accordingly.

The concept is similar to your computer login screen which you can login to different profile, and each profile has its own preference and settings.

I am interested of this feature because, I need to separate my iPhone preferences between work and personal.

I'm using iPhone 5 using 6.1.4., I'm also considering jailbreak options.

Comment: Is jailbreaking an option for you?

Comment: I can consider it

Comment: Can you please include this in your question? There is definitively no solution for your problem in the non-jailbreak-world.